Source for the practice of praying while attending a circumcision?
I've heard of a practice for those attending a circumcision to pray during the circumcision. Is there any known source for this?

http://www.frumtoronto.com/Main.asp?Menu_Tag=brismilah&BlogCategoryID=73

Do you mean at the very moment of the procedure? Before? After? While the baby is crying? Something in addition to whatever is traditionally included in the various nushaoth of a סדר ברית מילה?

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4255&st=&pgnum=22
